# Zoom in and out of a scene?

Tags: scenekit

What is the correct way to zoom in and out of a scene in SceneKit?

So when I enable the standard camera control in a scene and pinch in and out the scene gets bigger and smaller. What is that pinch really doing?

Is it changing the scale of the whole scene? Is it moving the camera closer?

I want to implement the same effect but programmatically.

What should I do to obtain the same effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pinch it's the field of view (`xFox` and `yFov` properties) of your camera that's changed. Changing the field of view is not the best way to zoom because it can dramatically change the perspective.

Moving the camera closer to your object is a good solution.

Also note that the "free camera" behavior is suitable for 3D viewers (such as Preview.app) but will rapidly become frustrating in any other app. At this point you might want to implement your own camera controller.

Comment: So I changed the xFov and I got the same effect. It worked. When you say implement your own camera controller... what would it so different from the standard one that would make it less frustrating? (just trying to understand what you mean). Thanks

Comment: I meant that if one is using the `allowsCameraControl` API and finds that he has to find tricks to make it work the way he wants, then re-implementing a camera controller from scratch might be a good idea. But it seems that that's already what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

At any given point the camera has a position in space, it has a rotation for each of its own axis compared to each of the world axis, to have a zoom in and zoom out, you have to move the camera in the +z/-z axis direction.

Along the Cameras own Z/-Z axis.

Answer (score 0):

For those on OSX, I used this in my SCNView subclass:

```
override func scrollWheel(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let cam = pointOfView!.camera
    cam!.xFov = cam!.xFov - Double(theEvent.deltaY)
    cam!.yFov = cam!.yFov - Double(theEvent.deltaY)
}
```

There are two (minor) problems that could be addressed with a little extra code. One is that the values can go negative, at which point the image is flipped inside-out. The other is that mouse acceleration can cause the zoom level to go too fast if you really spin the wheel. Limits on both of these would be a good idea, but in my app the behaviour was fine as it is above.